# Padding and adding binary strings in C

Tags: c, binary

I have been tasked with writing a program in C that takes strings of binary digits and adds them. The two strings can be different lengths, so before they are added, they need to be padded to the same size.

```
    //Make copy of strings with proper padding
char *aCopy = (char *)calloc(size+1,sizeof(char));
char *bCopy = (char *)calloc(size+1,sizeof(char));

int i;
for(i = size; i >= 0; i--)
{
  aCopy[i] = '0';
  bCopy[i] = '0';
}

for (i = strlen(a); i >= 0; i--)
  if (i == 0 && a[i]=='1') //Two's complement
    aCopy[i] = '1';
  else
    aCopy[size - i] = a[strlen(a)-i];

for (i = strlen(b); i >= 0; i--)
  if (i == 0 && b[i]=='1') //Two's complement
    bCopy[i] == '1';
  else
    bCopy[size - i] = b[strlen(b)-i];
```

I am having an issue where, if the lines commented "Two's complement" are run (they serve to move the leading 1 digit to the front of the padded string), the length of the padded string becomes one more than it should be. I cannot figure out why this is happening, and it is screwing up my calculations.

Edit: To clarify, an extra '0' char is being added to the end of the two's complement string.

Comment: You use `strlen` as if it is costless. It _is_ costly, and you use it unnecesarilly. Use an intermediate variable and evaluate `strlen` only once, as it is invariant.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie i am setting it to a string of '0' chars. Calloc sets it to the value 0 which denotes string termination,

Comment: Apologies for 2nd comment. I'll remove it.

Comment: where are the definitions of the array a and b, and the integer size?