# Adding two binary number strings - C

Tags: c, string, binary, point

I know there are a lot of information about this issue in the Internet and in particular at Stack - but I'm still stuck.

Given two binary number strings - we have to return their binary sum as a string.

Actually, I think I have the same issue as this guy's one: [Padding and adding binary strings in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42007535/padding-and-adding-binary-strings-in-c)

But I have done some additions and alternations as shown below:

```
    // This function validates the two strings are really representing two binary number, and we keep the size of each
int isNum(const char* num, int* sizeOfNum) {
  *sizeOfNum = 0;
  while (*num != '\0') {
    if (*num != '0' || *num != '1') {
      return 0;
    }
    *sizeOfNum += 1;
  }
  return 1;
}

char* sumOfBinString(const char* num1, const char* num2) {

    int* sizeOfNum1 = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int));
    int* sizeOfNum2 = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int));

    if (isNum(num1, sizeOfNum1) && isNum(num2, sizeOfNum2)) {

        if (*sizeOfNum1 > *sizeOfNum2) {
          int size = (*sizeOfNum1);
        }
        else {
          int size = (*sizeOfNum2);
        }
    }

        //This 'size' is actually the size of the longer binary number string, and plus one for the null-terminator
    char *num1Copy = (char *)malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));
    char *num2Copy = (char *)malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));

    int i;
    for(i = size; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      num1Copy[i] = '0';
      num2Copy[i] = '0';
    }

    for (i = *sizeOfNum1; i >= 0; i--)
      if (i == 0 && num1Copy[i]=='1') //Two's complement
        num1Copy[i] = '1';
      else
        num1Copy[size - i] = num1[*sizeOfNum1-i];

    for (i = *sizeOfNum2; i >= 0; i--)
      if (i == 0 && num2Copy[i]=='1') //Two's complement
        num2Copy[i] == '1';
      else
        num2Copy[size - i] = num2[*sizeOfNum2-i];
}
```

But I have no idea how to continue from here, as there are some cases where the carry can overflow, and I would need to "add" this digit to be the MSB.

Can someone help me continue from here?

Comment: After a quick glance, I can see that this line: `if (*num != '0' || *num != '1')` is wrong: it will *always* evaluate to "true" as the character cannot be both "0" and "1". Change `||` to `&&`.

Comment: When adding in 2's Complement, overflow bits are ignored. The length of the output is identical to the length of the inputs.

Comment: You shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` and you can use `calloc` to initialise bytes to 0.

Comment: Have you tested your conversion to 2s Complement? Normally, one would invert all the bits and add 1.

Comment: @LegendofPedro I'm actually not supposed to deal with this conversion. My only purpose here is to just add two binary number represented by char pointers - and return their binary sum by char pointer. If you can help me with the adding operation, as I don't know how to deal with the extra MSB which be necessary to be added...

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica Thank you. Can you see my comment to LegendofPedro above and maybe help me?

Comment: Are you given limits for how many significant digits might be present in the binary numbers?  If the numbers can be negative, you need to know whether it uses 2's-complement (probably), 1's-complement or sign-and-magnitude notation as well as how long the numbers are (or you need an explanation such as `-111` is used for `-7` decimal — a variant of sign-and-magnitude).  If the number of bits (binary digits) is less than 64, you can convert using `strtoll()` (carefully) and add natively.  Formatting is trickier; there isn't a standard function to do the job, but it isn't hard to write the code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is the task: Implement the function const char* binarySum(const char* num1, const char* num2) which gets 2 binary numbers, represented as strings, and returns the sum of them, represented as a string (binary number).  Note: In case of an invalid input - the function should return the string "0". e.g.  printf("%s\n", binarySum("101", "1")) ---> "110"

Comment: const char* result = binarySum("101", "111"); result is 1100 const char *result = binarySum("11001", "1111"); result is 101000

Comment: Would you get asked about `binarySum("101010101101101010101101010101110101010101010100010101111101010101010011100110101101010100100", "101010111111010101011101110101011010101110001000011110101110101011011010101001010101011101010101010110111111111111110101010111111")` (the longer number has 129 digits)?  Also, how are you supposed to avoid memory leaks if you don't save the value returned by `binarySum()` — your `printf("%s\n", binarySum("101", "1));` will leak unless you know a maximum length.  There are other issues to deal with too, but we don't know where you've got to in your learning.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler We have learnt about pointer, pointers to pointers, function pointers and all this stuff...

Answer (score 0):

To begin with:

```
int* sizeOfNum1 = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int));
int* sizeOfNum2 = (int*)(malloc(sizeof(int));

if (isNum(num1, sizeOfNum1) && isNum(num2, sizeOfNum2)) {

    if (*sizeOfNum1 > *sizeOfNum2) {
      int size = (*sizeOfNum1);
    }
    else {
      int size = (*sizeOfNum2);
    }
}
```

You don't need to use pointers for size bsc it's really easy to forget to `free` memory after or get into other problems. You can do it on int:

```
    int sizeOfNum1=0,sizeOfNum2=0;

    if (isNum(num1, &sizeOfNum1) && isNum(num2, &sizeOfNum2)) { //if u add & isNum can modify sizeofNum1 by itself (You give address of variable to function)

        if (sizeOfNum1 > sizeOfNum2) {
          int size = sizeOfNum1;
        }
        else {
          int size = sizeOfNum2;
        }
    }
```

For the math behind adding just like in school:

```
    111--- //carry line
      1100
   + 10100
    ------
    100000
```

In loop you got 2 itterators for each sizeOfNum and when it hit 0 you are adding only one with higher lenght to the output (ofc remeber that you need to check carry at all times like in example when in 1100 itterator will end carry is still 1 so you need watch out) some guide here:

```
int i,j;    
i=(size==sizeOfNum1)?size:sizeOfNum2;
j=((i==sizeOfNum1)&&(i==size))?sizeOfNum2:sizeOfNum1;
for(;i>=0;i--,j--){
   //here you are adding
}
```

Comment: Ofc in adding loop add bigger[i] smaller[j] only if j>=0

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your code at the bottom (the for loop). I don't know also the syntax with '?'

Comment: The syntax with ? is called Ternary Operator its just easier to write than if else more info here: https://guide.freecodecamp.org/c/ternary-operator/
i gonna be always size of the biggest number and j is for the smaller one. 1100 has lenght of 4 so we need to start from 3 index (its gonna be j itterator) and 10100 has length of 5 so its gonna start from 4 index (and it will be i iterator) 1 itteration of loop will add 3 and 4 index and 0 carry. Until j=1 i=2 this will add only 0s here we will get 1+1+0(carry) so we will get 0 and carry will be set to 1 rest is simple :)

Answer (score 0):

#### Diagnosis

There are many problems with the code shown in the question.  These include:

- It isn't a complete program, so we can't give a complete analysis.
- One bug that a compiler will normally report is in the section:

  ```
  if (i == 0 && num2Copy[i]=='1') //Two's complement
      num2Copy[i] == '1';
  else
      num2Copy[size - i] = num2[*sizeOfNum2-i];
  ```

  The `==` in the `if` body should be `=`, of course.  The compiler will normally complain about a statement with no effect.
- You allocate pointers `sizeOfNum1` and `sizeOfNum2` and fail to free them.  You should create simple variables and pass the address of those variables to your function.
- You allocate space for two copies of the longer string plus a null byte, but you don't allow space for the carry that might be necessary.  Adding two binary numbers might yield a result with one more digit than the longer input — the same happens with decimal addition, or indeed with addition in any other base.
- You don't check that the allocations succeed; you blithely assume they do.  This is dangerous.
- It isn't clear why you need two copies.
- You don't provide a mechanism to return any data.  Your `sumOfBinString()` function is declared to return a `char *`, but doesn't contain a `return` statement.  That's a bug.  Presumably, you should return one of the copies — but what should you do with the other?  Freeing it is the minimum — but you probably don't need it anyway.
- You could replace the code:

  ```
  int i;
  for(i = size; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    num1Copy[i] = '0';
    num2Copy[i] = '0';
  }
  ```

  with:

  ```
  memset(num1Copy, '0', size);
  memset(num2Copy, '0', size);
  num1Copy[size] = '\0';
  num2Copy[size] = '\0';
  ```

  That gives you two null-terminated strings — the memory returned by `malloc()` is not guaranteed to be zeroed, which is why there is `calloc()` too.
- I would probably use a local variable as the counter in `isNum()` and assign to the pointer parameter once, just before the return.  However, what you've written is defensible.
- You have the code fragment:

  ```
  if (isNum(num1, sizeOfNum1) && isNum(num2, sizeOfNum2)) {

      if (*sizeOfNum1 > *sizeOfNum2) {
        int size = (*sizeOfNum1);
      }
      else {
        int size = (*sizeOfNum2);
      }
  }

  char *num1Copy = (char *)malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char));
  ```

  The two different variables `size` are not used in their code blocks, and neither is accessible when `malloc()` is called.  That code won't compile.  If you supply non-compiling code, have the courtesy to say so, and include the text of the error message in the question.
- The "Two's complement" comments are mysterious.  You can't have two's complement binary values without knowing how big the values are.  You can have a 32-bit or a 64-bit two's complement, but without knowing how many digits are required, you can't tell whether the first one bit is a sign bit or just a regular magnitude bit.  Similar comments apply to one's complement values.  You could manage sign-and-magnitude using a `-` character to indicate negative numbers.  You then have to modify the processing considerably.  Your code can only possibly handle unsigned binary numbers.

  I suppose that if you mandate that positive numbers have a leading zero and negative numbers a leading one, then you can use two's complement, but leading zeros are normally treated as insignificant.  If you do use two's complement like that, you have a lot more work to do.
- I'm fairly sure there are other problems – but further diagnosis is probably not sensible.

#### Synthesis

Here's the code that I wrote to fulfill the assignment in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59095543/adding-two-binary-number-strings-c?noredirect=1#comment104426746_59095543):

> Implement the function `const char* binarySum(const char* num1, const char* num2)` which gets 2 binary numbers, represented as strings, and returns the sum of them, represented as a string (binary number). Note: In case of an invalid input, the function should return the string "0".
>
> ```
> printf("%s\n", binarySum("101", "1"))  // ---> "110"
> ```

The code I've written uses some library code that is available in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c`, `stderr.h`, `debug.c` and `debug.h` (and indirectly `kludge.c` and `kludge.h`) in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.  The macros and functions provided allow me to include debugging information in the code.

To compile the code (source code `binsum83.c`; test program `binsum83`), I built the program in a directory with a sub-directory `inc` containing the headers and another sub-directory `lib` containing a library, `libsoq.a`, with the library functions in it:

```
gcc -O3 -g -I./inc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -DTEST -DDEBUG binsum83.c -o binsum83 -L./lib  -lsoq
```

The `-DTEST` flag builds the program — if it is omitted, it creates a file containing only the exposed function `binarySum()` and hidden (`static`) functions with no `main()` function.  The `-DDEBUG` flag enables the tracing mechanism — if it is omitted, then the `-d level` option to set the debug level is still accepted, but it doesn't do anything useful.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "debug.h"
#include "stderr.h"

/* External interface - result is not constant */
extern char *binarySum(const char *s1, const char *s2);

static bool is_binary(const char *str)
{
    assert(*str != '\0');
    for (const char *digit = str; *digit != '\0'; digit++)
    {
        if (*digit != '0' && *digit != '1')
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

static inline size_t max(size_t s1, size_t s2) { return (s1 > s2) ? s1 : s2; }

static void reverse_bytes(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    assert(s2 >= s1);
    while (s1 < s2)
    {
        char t = *s1;
        *s1++ = *s2;
        *s2-- = t;
    }
}

static inline int binary_digit(const char *str, size_t len, size_t idx)
{
    int result = 0;
    if (idx < len)
        result = str[len - 1 - idx] - '0';
    DB_TRACE(3, "%s(): %16s (%2zu) [%2zu] = %d\n", __func__, str, len, idx, result);
    return result;
}

static const char *skip_leading_zeros(const char *s1)
{
    while (s1[0] == '0' && s1[1] != '\0')
        s1++;
    return s1;
}

char *binarySum(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    DB_TRACE(1, "-->> %s(): evaluate %s + %s\n", __func__, s1, s2);
    /* Return 0 if either of the inputs is not a valid binary number */
    if (!is_binary(s1) || !is_binary(s2))
        s1 = s2 = "0";
    s1 = skip_leading_zeros(s1);
    s2 = skip_leading_zeros(s2);
    size_t len1 = strlen(s1);
    size_t len2 = strlen(s2);
    size_t maxlen = max(len1, len2);
    DB_TRACE(2, "%s(): len(%s) = %zu; len(%s) = %zu; max = %zu\n", __func__, s1, len1, s2, len2, maxlen);
    char *result = malloc(maxlen + 2);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        DB_TRACKING();
        err_sysrem("%s(): failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", __func__, maxlen);
        return 0;
    }
    char *rp = result;
    int carry = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < maxlen; i++)
    {
        int d1 = binary_digit(s1, len1, i);
        int d2 = binary_digit(s2, len2, i);
        int r = d1 + d2 + carry;
        DB_TRACE(2, "%s(): d1 = %d, d2 = %d, c = %d, r = %d\n", __func__, d1, d2, carry, r);
        assert(r >= 0 && r <= 3);
        *rp++ = (r & 1) + '0';
        carry = r >> 1;
    }
    if (carry)
        *rp++ = '1';
    *rp = '\0';
    DB_TRACE(2, "%s(): reverse = %s\n", __func__, result);
    reverse_bytes(result, rp - 1);
    DB_TRACE(2, "%s(): forward = %s\n", __func__, result);
    DB_TRACE(1, "<<-- %s(): %s + %s = %s\n", __func__, s1, s2, result);
    return result;
}

#ifdef TEST

#include <unistd.h>

static const char optstr[] = "hd:";
static const char usestr[] = "[-h][-d debug] binary1 binary2";
static const char hlpstr[] =
    "  -d debug  Set debug level (0..3)\n"
    "  -h        Print this help message and exit\n"
    ;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    err_setarg0(argv[0]);
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, optstr)) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'd':
            db_setdebug(atoi(optarg));
            break;
        case 'h':
            err_help(usestr, hlpstr);
            /* NOTREACHED */
        default:
            err_usage(usestr);
            /* NOTREACHED */
        }
    }
    if (optind != argc - 2)
        err_usage(usestr);

    const char *num1 = argv[optind + 0];
    const char *num2 = argv[optind + 1];
    char *result = binarySum(num1, num2);
    if (result == 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    printf("%s + %s = %s\n", num1, num2, result);
    free(result);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#endif /* TEST */
```

The function declaration for `binarySum()` should be in a header that can be included when the function is needed.  All the other functions apart from `main()` are made `static` since they are not key functionality.  It would be possible to expose other functions as deemed appropriate — the `is_binary()` function could perhaps be usefully exposed.

The `is_binary()` function reports whether a string represents a binary number.  If assertions are disabled (`-DNEBUG` on the compiler command line), then it treats an empty string as valid — and the rest of the code works, treating it as zero (but diagnostic printing is a little screwy).

The `max()` function is often written as a macro — using a `static inline` function is equivalent but imposes some type-safety that it is not worth attempting with a macro.

The `reverse_bytes()` function reverses the bytes in the range between `s1` and `s2` inclusive.  It is easiest for the main function to generate the result with the LSB (least significant bit) first in the string.  This code is used to reverse the string.  Note that the assertion is only safe if `s1` and `s2` both point to valid addresses in the same array — otherwise, you invoke undefined behaviour.  The code obeys that requirement.

The `binary_digit()` function is a key function.  It is given a string, the length of the string (it might almost be reasonable to add `assert(strlen(str) == len)`) and a position.  The bytes in the string are numbered so that the last byte is 0, the first is `len - 1`; if the requested position is outside the length of the string, it is treated as a (leading) zero byte.  (Note that the bytes are the character representation of bits; that can be confusing.)

The `skip_leading_zeros()` function does precisely that, returning a pointer to the first `1` digit in the string, but if the number is zero, it returns a pointer to the last `0` instead of the first `1`.  This refinement makes the debugging output more sane.

The core function is `binarySum()`.  I've modified the return type from `const char *` to `char *` because if you don't do that, you have to cast the value when it is passed to `free()` (you have to write `free((void *)result)` or similar, which looks clunky).  It finds the length of the strings after leading zeros are skipped, then allocates enough space for the longer string plus one extra digit and a null terminator (hence `+ 2` in the call to `malloc()`).  If the memory allocation fails, it forcibly reports a warning via `err_sysrem()` and returns a null pointer.  You could drop the error message and simply return a null pointer.  It then scans through the two strings from right-to-left using `binary_digit()` to establish the correct digits.  This stores the result in reverse order but can handle the final carry easily.  It then reverses the digits to get the result in the normal order and returns that to the calling code.

The `main()` function has option handling to allow you to set the debug level (`-d debug`), and to get help (I use `-h` for help; GNU recommends `--help` but I don't use `getopt_long()`).  It then checks that there are precisely two arguments left, and adds those.  This version silently accepts invalid inputs and converts the result to `0`; a previous version scanned the arguments and validated that they were binary before calling `binarySum()`.

Note that it is crucial to capture the value returned by `binarySum()` so that it can be freed.  Thus the example code in the assignment is defective; it should be more like:

```
const char *result = binarySum("101", "1");
printf("%s\n", result);
free(result);
```

It would not be hard to remove the debugging code or the error reporting code.  The surviving assertion could also be removed.

I used a test script like this (`test.binsum83.sh`):

```
binsum83 -d 3 001 000001
binsum83 -d 4 000 00000
binsum83 -d 4 000 000001
binsum83 -d 4 001 000001
binsum83 -d 5 00011010110101 000001
binsum83 -d 5 001 000001
binsum83 0 0
binsum83 0 1
binsum83 000 00000
binsum83 000 000001
binsum83 00011010110101 000001
binsum83 001 000001
binsum83 011011101 000001
binsum83 1 1
binsum83 101 1
binsum83 101 111
binsum83 101010101101101010101101010101110101010101010100010101111101010101010011100110101101010100100 101010111111010101011101110101011010101110001000011110101110101011011010101001010101011101010101010110111111111111110101010111111 
binsum83 101111 10001
binsum83 11001 1111
binsum83 11010 000001
binsum83 111 1
```

The long numbers are from my comment to the question.  The output is:

```
$ sh -x test.binsum83.sh
+ binsum83 -d 3 001 000001
-->> binarySum(): evaluate 001 + 000001
binarySum(): len(1) = 1; len(1) = 1; max = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 0] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 0] = 1
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 1, c = 0, r = 2
binarySum(): reverse = 01
binarySum(): forward = 10
<<-- binarySum(): 1 + 1 = 10
001 + 000001 = 10
+ binsum83 -d 4 000 00000
-->> binarySum(): evaluate 000 + 00000
binarySum(): len(0) = 1; len(0) = 1; max = 1
binary_digit():                0 ( 1) [ 0] = 0
binary_digit():                0 ( 1) [ 0] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 0, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 0
binarySum(): reverse = 0
binarySum(): forward = 0
<<-- binarySum(): 0 + 0 = 0
000 + 00000 = 0
+ binsum83 -d 4 000 000001
-->> binarySum(): evaluate 000 + 000001
binarySum(): len(0) = 1; len(1) = 1; max = 1
binary_digit():                0 ( 1) [ 0] = 0
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 0] = 1
binarySum(): d1 = 0, d2 = 1, c = 0, r = 1
binarySum(): reverse = 1
binarySum(): forward = 1
<<-- binarySum(): 0 + 1 = 1
000 + 000001 = 1
+ binsum83 -d 4 001 000001
-->> binarySum(): evaluate 001 + 000001
binarySum(): len(1) = 1; len(1) = 1; max = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 0] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 0] = 1
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 1, c = 0, r = 2
binarySum(): reverse = 01
binarySum(): forward = 10
<<-- binarySum(): 1 + 1 = 10
001 + 000001 = 10
+ binsum83 -d 5 00011010110101 000001
-->> binarySum(): evaluate 00011010110101 + 000001
binarySum(): len(11010110101) = 11; len(1) = 1; max = 11
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 0] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 0] = 1
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 1, c = 0, r = 2
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 1] = 0
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 1] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 0, d2 = 0, c = 1, r = 1
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 2] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 2] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 1
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 3] = 0
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 3] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 0, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 0
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 4] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 4] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 1
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 5] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 5] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 1
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 6] = 0
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 6] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 0, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 0
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 7] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 7] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 1
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 8] = 0
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 8] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 0, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 0
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [ 9] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 9] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 1
binary_digit():      11010110101 (11) [10] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [10] = 0
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 0, c = 0, r = 1
binarySum(): reverse = 01101101011
binarySum(): forward = 11010110110
<<-- binarySum(): 11010110101 + 1 = 11010110110
00011010110101 + 000001 = 11010110110
+ binsum83 -d 5 001 000001
-->> binarySum(): evaluate 001 + 000001
binarySum(): len(1) = 1; len(1) = 1; max = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 0] = 1
binary_digit():                1 ( 1) [ 0] = 1
binarySum(): d1 = 1, d2 = 1, c = 0, r = 2
binarySum(): reverse = 01
binarySum(): forward = 10
<<-- binarySum(): 1 + 1 = 10
001 + 000001 = 10
+ binsum83 0 0
0 + 0 = 0
+ binsum83 0 1
0 + 1 = 1
+ binsum83 000 00000
000 + 00000 = 0
+ binsum83 000 000001
000 + 000001 = 1
+ binsum83 00011010110101 000001
00011010110101 + 000001 = 11010110110
+ binsum83 001 000001
001 + 000001 = 10
+ binsum83 011011101 000001
011011101 + 000001 = 11011110
+ binsum83 1 1
1 + 1 = 10
+ binsum83 101 1
101 + 1 = 110
+ binsum83 101 111
101 + 111 = 1100
+ binsum83 101010101101101010101101010101110101010101010100010101111101010101010011100110101101010100100 101010111111010101011101110101011010101110001000011110101110101011011010101001010101011101010101010110111111111111110101010111111
101010101101101010101101010101110101010101010100010101111101010101010011100110101101010100100 + 101010111111010101011101110101011010101110001000011110101110101011011010101001010101011101010101010110111111111111110101010111111 = 101010111111010101011101110101011011011000110110001001011100000001001111111110101001110011010010101100010011100110100010101100011
+ binsum83 101111 10001
101111 + 10001 = 1000000
+ binsum83 11001 1111
11001 + 1111 = 101000
+ binsum83 11010 000001
11010 + 000001 = 11011
+ binsum83 111 1
111 + 1 = 1000
$
```

Using `bc` confirms the long addition.  Note that you need to set the `obase` before you set the `ibase`, or you need to specify `ibase = 2; obase = 10`.  If you paste the output that `bc` splits over two lines with a backslash at the end of the first, that is the same as the test script output above.

```
$  bc
bc 1.06
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
obase=2
ibase=2
101010101101101010101101010101110101010101010100010101111101010101010011100110101101010100100 + 101010111111010101011101110101011010101110001000011110101110101011011010101001010101011101010101010110111111111111110101010111111 
10101011111101010101110111010101101101100011011000100101110000000100\
1111111110101001110011010010101100010011100110100010101100011
quit
$
```